# Objective-C: New Random Errors in Header File for Category

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am experiencing an issue where I now have errors in a file that was working fine just yesterday.  I have made no changes to the file, yet I have these new errors.  My code is below, with the errors commented by each line:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (stringByStrippingHTML) // Error 1: Missing "@end" Error 2: Expected a type Error 3: Method type specifier must start with '-' or '+'

- (NSString *) stripHTML; // Expected selector for Objective-C method

@end
```

Why did these errors suddenly appear and what can I do to fix them?

Comment: Try to clean the project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that, along with simply remaking the file, and neither works.  Also, restarting Xcode and my computer were unsuccessful.

Comment: Does this category contains only these 4 lines?

Comment: Yes, that is all of the code for the header file of the category.

Comment: You're subclassing NSString?

Comment: Yes, this category is subclassing NSString.

Comment: @ErikHanson So is this now a category or a subclass?

Comment: Sorry, it's a category for NSString.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the derived data (Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> "delete derived data" button), restarting Xcode, cleaning, and rebuilding? (...Xcode hates me late at night... ;)

Comment: Something is most likely wrong with the file that you imported immediately before this one.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, and it turns out that the error is caused because I've typed in a minus '-' sign (by mistake) in the file just above the file that's giving the problem.

This is the beginning of the file just above the one giving the error:

```
-//
//  AsyncUIImageView.m
//  TableView
//
//  Created by www.thecodecrate.com on 23/01/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 www.TheCodeCrate.com. All rights reserved.
//
//================================================================================
#import "AsyncUIImageView.h"
...
```

See the '-' at the top?  Once that was removed, the damn problem went away!

Answer (score 0):

I created a file with the exact same code and it compiles fine. When I deleted the `@end` line I got the same error messages you list.

1. Are you absolutely sure your file contains exactly the code in your question? Try copying the code from your question and pasting it into your file.
2. `Error 1: Missing "@end"` may suggest there is a garbled character in your file. If you have BBEdit try "Zap Gremlins". If not, you can download the trial version.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I copied and pasted my code into my question, so it is the exact same.  Like I said in my initial question, it worked fine yesterday.  At some point, I just got these errors and I'm not sure why they just popped up.

Comment: Strange. Something seems to be making that `@end` statement invisible to Xcode. If you delete `- (NSString *) stripHTML;` do you still get the error?

Comment: Yes, when I removed that line, the errors were still there.  Since I only use this method in a couple of places, I tried getting rid of the category and just placing the code in spot that made sense.  Now, I have new errors, not in the file with my stripHTML method, but in other, unrelated files.

Answer (score 0):

Things don't just happen randomly. You think you made no changes, but you have made some change. Compare your current files with the previous, working version. You have the previous working version, somewhere, right? If not, here's a valuable lesson: Make sure that you use a source code control system that lets you access previous versions of your code. And you have a tool that can compare your current version with a previous one, right? If not, get one as soon as possible.

The error is quite possible a missing @end in a header file that you included before this one.